# Semaphore On Multiple Producer Single Consumer Problem

Tags: c++, multithreading

I need to suggestion on this case studies on C++.

I have taken Queue where multiple Thread 20 Producer thread is writing on it.there is single Consumer thread which will Read from the queue and process it.
I am planning to use critical section and Semaphore to achieve synchronization.

AddTail-Adding message in the Queue.
RemoveHead-Remove data from Queue.

I have restricted the queue length to 10.

Crtical section will protect wrting or/Reading problem.
Semaphore will synchronized access to the queue.

Let me know any other POssible solution on this.

Comment: 20 Producers and only queue length of 10. You would be dropping loads of data. What if all the 20 producers want to write data at the same time ? How do you decide what to keep and what to drop ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105382/multiple-producers-single-consumer/5105795#5105795 is another solution, but based on that question, you probably can't use condition variables

Comment: @DumbCoder: If the queue is full, you can make it so that the producers block until the semaphore count becomes non-zero again, before they enqueue their data. This is known as a *blocking bounded queue*. Of course, this technique is not feasible for a real-time application. In that case, like you said, packets would have to be dropped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to write such a queue. For example, you could use a mutex and a condition variable as in my example at http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html

Herb Sutter discusses queues in his articles at Dr Dobb's. See http://www.drdobbs.com/high-performance-computing/211601363 and http://www.drdobbs.com/high-performance-computing/210604448