# Qt - How to save downloaded data for a multipart downloader

Tags: qt, multipart, download-manager, qfile

I'm writing a multipart downloader in Qt. Multiple `QNetWorkRequest` with http header "Range" are used to download a file. Now I write data received in each part(`QNetworkReply`) to file.part1, file.part2, etc.

Is it possible to write data to the same file simultaneously? Do I have to implement a lock for it and which is the best way to save data in my application?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just merge the file parts when you are finished? You can write the parts to a `QFile` easily. Perhaps something about the approach or the data keeps you from doing this, but if you can, it's probably the approach I would take before dealing with treating a `QFile` as a shared resource.

If you want multiple concurrent replies to be able to write to and access the `QFile`, then yes, the `QFile` becomes a shared resource. As far as I know, you're going to need to lock it. At that point, you have several options. You can have the slot(s) handling the replies attempt to acquire a `QSemaphore`, you can use `QMutex` and `QMutexLocker` if you'd prefer to lock on a mutex. You could treat it as a multiple producer (the various QNetworkReplys) single consumer (whatever is writing to the file) problem ([here's a Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193951/semaphore-on-multiple-producer-single-consumer-problem) that provides some useful links) if you want to go that route. In short, there are numerous approaches here, all of which I think are more of a hassle than simply merging the `file.part`'s at the end if you're able to go that route.

In terms of merging to a single `QFile` concurrently, there may be an easier Qt way of doing it, but I've never found it. Perhaps someone else can chime in if such a method exists.

I'm not sure what you mean by "which is the best way to save data in my application?" Are you referring to saving application specific settings in a persistent manner? If so, look into [`QSettings`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html). If you're referring to saving the data you're downloading, I'd probably write it to a `QFile`, just like you appear to be doing. Although it's hard to know for sure without knowing more about what you're downloading.

Answer (score 1):

The "Qt way" would be the event driven way - each downloader threaded object can send its downloaded buffer via a queued connection to a single file writer threaded object, no need to add more locking, just leverage the locking that Qt's already paying anyway.

Doing anything more fine grained or performance optimized is wildly redundant, unless your network rates exceed the speed of your storage.

It may be worth mentioning keeping the writing chunks a decent size, I'd suggest at least 32k or 64k if you are really memory constrained, smaller chunks can introduce needless overheads in terms of cpu time, poor storage performance, excessive file fragmentation and the most undesirable - write amplification.

And finally, a more important consideration would be how you do multi part. Most downloaders I've seen simply split the file in n equally sized chunks and start concurrently downloading and writing each one. But you could also do a "creeping" smaller window downloads, which will enable sequential reception of data while still leveraging concurrent downloading to saturate the network, and most if not all file systems and storage medium will appreciate that good will.